# How to secure RepositoryRestController

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Let's say I have 2 have to entities:

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    @NotEmpty
    private String title;
    @NotEmpty
    @Lob
    private String html;
    @NotEmpty
    @Lob
    private String text;
    @ManyToOne
    private Topic topic;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "content_media", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "content_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "media_id")})
    private Set<Media> medias = new HashSet<>();
    @CreatedBy
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn
    private User createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn
    private User lastModifiedBy;
    ...
}
@Entity
public class Media {
    @NotEmpty
    private String localPath;
    @NotEmpty
    private String fileName;
    private long fileLength;
    private String fileType;
    private int focusPointX;
    private int focusPointY;
    ...
}
```

And I'm exposing them using:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public interface MediaRepository extends JpaRepository<Media, Long> {
}
@RepositoryRestController
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
}
```

I want these controllers to be secure. Let me explain myself.

- If logged in user does not have ROLE_ADMIN, Medias should only be
  accessable through posts and /medias/ should return 403 or 404
- Only users that have ROLE_USER should be able to create to posts
- Only the user that have created the post or the ones that have the ROLE_ADMIN should be able to update post.
- Only the users that have ROLE_ADMIN should be able to delete posts

Is there a way to do these using RepositoryRestController and Spring Security or RepositoryRestController is for public resources only and I should write service layer myself using RestController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can directly use Spring Security with Spring Data REST. You need to define the security of your routes using Spring Security Configuration as shown below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().
        antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/posts").hasRole("USER").
        antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/posts/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and().
        csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

Repository methods will be secured using Spring Security annotations. e.g.

```
@RepositoryRestController
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    void delete(Long aLong);
}
```

Code above is just a pointer. You can customize it as per your needs. [Here is the link to Spring Data examples repository.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security)

**Update**
To handle the update of the post by the user who created or by any user who is in ADMIN_ROLE you need to create a controller class and define a method with to handle the update

```
@RequestMapping(method={RequestMethod.PUT}, value={"posts/{id}"})
public void updatePost(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    //Fetch the authenticated user name
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
    Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();

    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
    }

    // Make a database call to verify if the user is owner of the post
    Post post = postRepository.getPostByUserName(String username, Long postId);

    if (post == null && !request.isUserInRole("ADMIN");) {
        //return 403 error code
    }

    //proceed with the update
}
```

Comment: I accepted the answer but your answer does not cover 
"Only the user that have created the post ... should be able to update post.".